# Dynamic Geometry Software for Straight-edge and Compass Constructions

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, math-software, education, learning

Geogebra is a very good dynamic geometry software. It has so many default tools, e.g. parallel line, angle bisector, tangent to the circle, inscribed and circumscribed circles, etc. But I want the tools be limited just to the straight-edge and compass, and then construct every other tool from the scratch and make new tools ("macro"s).

I can customize Geogebra toolbar, but for some reasons it may be better to use a software which its default tools are just straight-edge and compass, and the user can save macros he makes. Does such a software exist?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe The geometers sketchpad http://www.dynamicgeometry.com/ but even that has parallel lines, perpendicular lines and more like that

Answer (score 1):

I can describe how I will do it with Dr. Geo, a free interactive geometry software I am developing.

1. From the menu **Edit>Customise interface**, you select the tools you want: select and move, point, circle, segment and macro tools,

[Select only the tools you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tzU1.png)

2. Then you save your empty sketch under the name **Minimimal** for example,
3. Next time you load the Minimal sketch its comes with your customized UI, including the tools to register and play macro-construction.

[Geometric canvas with minimal tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTNqI.png)

I use this feature to limit the tools used for primary school activities.

Answer (score 1):

A custom Geogebra toolbar based on compass and straightedge can be found at [this page](https://www.geogebra.org/m/kGPuEwBy). It allows you to build new tools and add them to the toolbar.

If you don't want to allow the creation of new tools, and want to see the compass and straightedge more clearly, [this example](https://www.geogebra.org/m/PN9Bfv6Z) can serve as a model.

To be clear, neither of these applets were made by me, and the authors can be found at the bottom of the respective pages.

Answer (score 0):

[Sketchometry](http://sketchometry.org/) comes with a minimal interface with gesture controls to construct straight line and circle.